# Solving same length and scale foreign key in Pyton3.4 error (using sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table,

```
class RMMASTST(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'RMMASTST'
  RecorderID = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
  metering_data = relationship("StatsMetering", backref="recorder")
```

Now, I want to create a second table:

```
class StatsMetering(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'StatsMetering'
  RecorderID = Column(String(50), ForeignKey(RMMASTST.RecorderID), primary_key=True)
```

However, when I execute the script, I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'RMMASTST.RecorderID' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'StatsMetering.RecorderID' in foreign key 'FK__StatsMete__Recor__4B7734FF'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale. (1753) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Does anyone know why I keep on getting this error? Obviously, these are extracts from the script. All tables are created by using:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(Engine)
```

Comment: tested on **SQLite** and **PostgreSQL**, works fine

Comment: When I open the table through access (the RMMASTST) one, "RecorderID" has a field size of 14. It seems like it's ignoring my instruction to set the size to 50.

Comment: Well colour me confused - I changed the size to 14 in both, and now it works.

Comment: maybe `RMMASTST` table was created before with `String(14)`?

Comment: That might have been the case, thanks. I created a new Database and ran the script again with no problems.

Comment: you probably should answer your own question or i can do it for you

Comment: Thanks, just did that. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted works correctly, if you get this type of error, just make sure that no tables were created already that might have different lengths.